# Why do Python's datetime.strftime('%w') and datetime.weekday() use different indexes for the days of the week?

Tags: python, datetime

In Python, showing the day of the week as an integer using `datetime.strftime()` shows a different result than using `datetime.weekday()`.

```
>>> import datetime
>>> now = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> now.strftime('%A')
'Sunday'
>>> now.strftime('%w') # Day of the week as an integer.
'0'
>>> now.weekday() # Day of the week as an integer, a different way.
6
```

With `strftime()`, the string format `%w` has Sunday as the first day of the week.  With `weekday()`, it's Monday instead.

**What's the history of why these two are different?**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Python's `strftime` function emulates that in the c library.  Thus, the motivation that `%w` returns `0` for a Sunday comes entirely from that.

In contrast, the method `date.weekday()` returns a `6` for Sunday as it seeks to match the behaviour of the much older `time` module.  Within that module times are generally represented by a `struct_time` and within this, `struct_time.tm_day` uses a `6` to represent a Sunday.

The correct question then becomes ... why does `time.struct_time` represent a Sunday as a `6`, when the C library's `tm` struct uses a `0` ??

And the answer is ... because it just does.  This behaviour has existed ever since Guido first checked in `gmtime` and `localtime` functions in 1993.

And Guido cannot be wrong ... so you best ask him.

Comment: Well Guido is Italian.  And, as Foo Bah implied, Monday is the first day of the week in Italy.

Comment: @MikeM.Lin Guido is Dutch. Hence "Although that way may not be obvious at first unless you're Dutch".

Comment: I equated "Guido" with "Italian".  That was so wrong of me :-P  I'm from New York, if that makes it any more excusable.

Comment: Why not use ISO 8601 numbering for all, instead of mixing uncompatible functions, which is both hideous and strongly unpythonic, even if blessed by Guido.

Answer (score 5):

Originally, the ISO 8601 standard used `1 .. 7` to represent Monday through Sunday.  For convenience, later on the interpretation `0=Sunday` was permitted.

If you want to use something that is more consistent, try using `isoweekday`

The `0=Monday` standard is the European convention.  I guess that's no surprise :P

Comment: This provides no more consistency whatsoever.  Then the question becomes why does `%w` render as `0` while `isoweekday()` returns `7`.

Comment: @Donkopotamus the issue is that there are multiple standards and conventions  involved (such as the ISO standard and US convention and European convention).  In some versions of strftime (like php) there is an explicit option to use the US mode (iirc it was `%u` or `%U`.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe `weekday` is based on locale while `strftime` is not? Because I have different output:

```
In [14]: d.strftime("%A")
Out[14]: 'Sunday'

In [15]: d.strftime("%w")
Out[15]: '0'

In [16]: now.weekday()
Out[16]: 0
```