# Getting a date from a week number

Tags: python

I am trying to get a date based on a number of the week, but there are some annoyances.

The `date.weekday()` returns the day of the week where 0 in Monday and 6 is Sunday.

The `%w` directive of `date.strftime()` and `date.strptime()` uses the 0 for Sunday and 6 for Saturday.

This causes some really annoying issues when trying to figure out a date given a week number from `date.weekday()`.

Is there a better way of getting a date from a week number?

**EDIT:**

Added the example.

```
import datetime

original_date = datetime.date(2014, 8, 24)
week_of_the_date = original_date.isocalendar()[1] # 34
day_of_the_date = original_date.isocalendar()[2] # 7
temp = '{0} {1} {2}'.format(*(2014, week_of_the_date, day_of_the_date-1))
date_from_week = datetime.datetime.strptime(temp, '%Y %W %w')
week_from_new_date = date_from_week.isocalendar()[1] # 35!!
```

**EDIT 2:**
I ultimately put the date stuff in the view (using jQuery UI), it has more consistent notions of weeks.

Comment: What exactly is a week number in this context, and what does `date.weekday` have to do with it? Sample input and output would be helpful.

Comment: Ah, didn't know about that problem, very ugly inconsistency! Different, but related question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7550726/2647279)

Comment: Week number (usually?) refers to [ISO week date](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date). Regarding the difference in weekday between time and datetime modules, you're right, it's hideous.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper Sure. I've added an example.

Comment: Possibly relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/304256/whats-the-best-way-to-find-the-inverse-of-datetime-isocalendar

Comment: I think the Sunday vs. Monday distinction between `weekday` and `strftime` using `%W` is moot - you could use `isoweekday` to get those to line up. The real problem is that `strftime`, based on the underlying C function, determines the first week of the year differently than the ISO definition. With `%W` the docs say: " All days in a new year preceding the first Monday are considered to be in week 0". ISO calendars count the week containing the first Thursday as the first week, for reasons I do not understand, and it doesn't look like there's a nicer way to reverse that than the answer linked.

Comment: There's also this module someone linked off one of the answers linked on that older answer: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/isoweek/

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper You should probably post your last two comments as an answer.

Comment: @SylvainLeroux - I suppose there's enough actual information there that I'm not trying to take credit for pointing out a dupe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the Sunday vs. Monday distinction between `weekday` and `strftime` using `%W` is moot - you could use `isoweekday` to get those to line up, or `%U` in `strftime` if you wanted Sunday as the first day of the week. The real problem is that `strftime`, based on the underlying C function, determines the first week of the year differently than the ISO definition. With `%W` the docs say: " All days in a new year preceding the first Monday are considered to be in week 0". ISO calendars count the week containing the first Thursday as the first week, for reasons I do not understand.

Two ways I found to work with ISO weeks, either just getting `datetime.date` instances back or supporting a variety of operations, are:

1. this answer with a simple `timedelta` approach:
   [What's the best way to find the inverse of datetime.isocalendar()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304256/whats-the-best-way-to-find-the-inverse-of-datetime-isocalendar)
2. this third-party library: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/isoweek/